# How do I Detect if the Mouse is Moving on Screen in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 360 camera movement for my game called PROTOTYPE. I need a function or something to detect if the mouse is moving and in which direction on the x axis it is, to set an offset for the Camera Smoothing script, but I don't know any. Could somebody plz help me? Here is the Camera Smoothing script if u need it:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    
    public float smoothSpeed = 0.125f;
    
    public Vector3 offset;
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
        Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
        transform.position = smoothedPosition;
    
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to move your camera with your mouse, 360° around your character and also that script is attached to your player.

In order to do that, your FixedUpdate should look like this:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float horizontalAxis = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"); // Getting the current mouse axis (left-right)
    float verticalAxis = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"); // Getting the current mouse axis (up-down)

    transform.RotateAround(player.transform.position, -Vector3.up, horizontalAxis * smoothSpeed);
    transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, transform.right, verticalAxis * smoothSpeed);
}
```